# Did Susie Greene's pregnancy ever get resolved?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, curb-your-enthusiasm

In the season 3 episode [Nanny From Hell](http://curb-your-enthusiasm.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nanny_From_Hell), Jeff tells Larry that Susie is pregnant, so Larry tries to persuade the Greenes to hire a nanny that he knows. The pregnancy never gets mentioned after that episode, as far as I can tell. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Susie Greene's pregnancy is referred to, obliquely, in just one subsequent episode.  The actress, Susie Essman, described the situation in an interview for *[Something Jewish](http://www.somethingjewish.co.uk/articles/2404_susie_essman_intervi.htm)*:

> In series two, we're told Susie is pregnant but we never see a baby – what happened?
>
> It was never mentioned again. There are so many inconsistences in the show. The only reason he had me pregnant was because of the episode where I fall out of a window on to a pile of sponge cakes. Then it was never mentioned again. The next season we make one little reference to it, in the episode with the studded sweatshirts, I made a reference to the fact that I loved designing clothes out of my own home because it was easy with the new baby. But it has never been discussed since.

The studded shirts episode was "[Ben's Birthday Party](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=curb-your-enthusiasm&episode=s04e02)" from season 4 (since the pregnancy was mentioned in season 3, not season 2 as the interviewer thought).  Her line was

> The thing that's so great about these shirts is that I've got the business from the house and I can take care of the baby.